# Switch from increment to decrement when reach the end of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through an array. when `current===arr.length` I want to decrement `current` again. Then, when `current === 0` I want to increment `current` again.

Below is the code I have. does my question make sense? i cannot figure out the logic in my head.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4],
    current = 0;

$('body').click(function(){
    console.log(arr[current]);
    current++;
    if(current === (arr.length -1)){
        current--;
    }
});
```

Comment: `current` will never reach `0` if all you do is decrement it once after it reaches `arr.length`. In other words, you wait for `current` to be `4`, then you decrement it to `3`, but then you increment back to `4`, then back to `3` and so on.

Comment: @nem035 i know, exactly, and thats where I am unsure of the logic to set it back to `0` and only increment again when it reaches there. I have taken many different approaches but cannot get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super pretty, but it's what I came up with quickly:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4],
    current = 0,
    dir = "up";

$('body').click(function(){
    if(current === arr.length - 1){
        dir = "down";
    } else if(current === 0){
        dir = "up";
    }

    switch(dir) {
        case "up":
           current++;
           break;
        case "down":
           current--;
           break;
    }

    console.log(arr[current]);
});
```

Comment: cheers for the answer @SeanKendle. perhaps it is essential to introduce another variable

Comment: I think you might want to look for arr.length - 1, though, edited my answer, check  on that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is pretty much the same as @SeanKendle. I just use a 3rd var because it makes the code cleaner IMO.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var current = 0;
var modifier = 1; 

$('body').click(function(){        
    if(current === arr.length -1){
        modifier = -1;
    }
    else if(current === 0){
        modifier = 1;
    }  
  current = current + modifier;
  console.log(arr[current]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could us an incrementor which can be negative.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4],
    current = 0,
    inc = 1;

$('body').click(function(){
    console.log(arr[current]);
    current += inc;
    if (current === arr.length || current < 0) {
        inc *= -1;
        current += 2 * inc;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl...

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4],
    current = 0,
    increment = true;

$('body').click(function(){
    console.log(arr[current]);

    if(current === arr.length - 1){
        increment = false;
    } else if (current === 0) {
        increment = true;
    }

    if(increment) {
        current++;
    } else {
        current--;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, an array with n elements has 2 * n - 2 different states. So we reset it with % and transform the index when accessing the array.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4],
    current = 0;

$('body').click(function(){
    console.log(arr[current>=arr.length?arr.length-2-(current-arr.length):current]);
    current = ++current % ( 2 * arr.length - 2 );
});
```